# Web filtering using OpenDNS for multiple home network computers

Tags: networking, web, opendns

I want to filter websites by category using [OpenDNS Basic](http://www.opendns.com/start/). Do I have to create an OpenDNS account per PC and then configure each manually?

How do I link up multiple PCs to one OpenDNS Dashboard so I can configure/view stats for all home computers in one place?

If nothing works I'll have to simple settle with the [Family Shield](http://www.opendns.com/familyshield/) for now.

Comment: ServerFault?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to create a new account for each PC.

If they're on the same network (Same Public IP), you simply point the DNS server of each PC to OpenDNS, and they'll use  your settings automatically after you've set them up.

If they are on different Public IP you simply login to your existing account on each IP and add them to your account. If you do this for the first time, you have to give them some personal information so your users can reach you.

Comment: You can also configure DNS on the router so all computers on the network will use OpenDNS by default.

Comment: If I only configure my router, do I still have to make an OpenDNS account and configure its filtering?

Comment: @Jeremy, yes just sign up for one OpenDNS account.  It will filter all computers on your IP address when you configure your router to use and pass OpenDNS servers.  I think they even have a service that lets you filter on a dynamic IP address, but I haven't used that before.